# SQL - How to select a row from a table with a specific data value and a key that only occurs once

Tags: mysql, sql

How can I select the USER field from table A where the data field is 'A' and the user value only occurs once?

Example:

```
 tblData (A)
+--------++--------+
|  USER  |   DATA  |
+--------++--------+
|   1    |    A    |
|   1    |    B    |
|   2    |    A    |
+--------++--------+
```

Desired result: user: 2

Comment: Wouldn't your expected result be user 1 and 2?

Comment: Desired Result sorry.

Comment: @hybr1d191, were you ever able to solve this? Just curious what you used to accomplish this query.

Answer (score 3):

There might be an easier/prettier solution but this one should work

```
SELECT ID FROM A A1
WHERE A1.DATA = 'A'
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM A A2
                WHERE A2.DATA <> 'A'
                AND A1.ID = A2.ID)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT a.id
FROM tableA a
WHERE a.data = 'A'
AND a.id NOT IN (SELECT b.id
                 FROM tableA b
                 WHERE b.id != 'A');
```

This should return only 2 as a result as the record with 1 and A will be excluded by the `NOT IN` clause

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT ID FROM A
GROUP BY ID
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN DATA <> 'A' THEN 1 END) = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using an aggregate function and a subquery.

This query here will return a list of all users that have only one row:

```
SELECT user, COUNT(*)
FROM test
GROUP BY user
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
```

Now, you can join this table with the original table on the condition that the user fields are equal and the data field is equal to 'A':

```
SELECT t2.user
FROM test t2
JOIN (
    SELECT user, COUNT(*)
    FROM test
    GROUP BY user
    HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
    ) AS t1
ON t2.user = t1.USER
WHERE t2.data = 'A';
```

Here's the [SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fef2a/7/0).

Answer (score 0):

1. Group by `USER`.
2. Count all rows in a group.
3. Count all rows in a group that have `A`.
4. Return only those users where the counts match.

```
SELECT USER
FROM tblData
GROUP BY USER
HAVING COUNT(*) = COUNT(CASE DATA WHEN 'A' THEN 1 END)
          /*  or: COUNT(DATA = 'A' OR NULL), which is MySQL-sepcific */
;
```

The above assumes that all `(USER, DATA)` combinations are unique.